# Old passport with no visas was destroyed, now applying for a new US visa

Tags: visas, usa, passports, indian-citizens, applications

My father is applying for a US visa for the first time. In the interview process he was asked to bring his old passport too, which unfortunately he had destroyed after it expired many years ago. He never travelled outside India on this old passport. Does he need to bring some kind of document proving that he had an old passport and had no visa on it? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: He doesn't HAVE to however he can if he wishes to. I believe the passport issuing agency will have proof of the previous passport. Unnecessary though IMHO

Comment: In the states, you can just say it was lost, and then bring valid identification (we can use our Drivers License even) to apply for a replacement passport.  Once he receives the new one, apply for the visa.  Again, this is in the states, so I'm leaving it as a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Some Indian passports mention the number of the previous passport; if your father's does, he needs to keep that referenced passport with the present one ALWAYS. Under no circumstance are you supposed to throw it away. If the previous passport number is mentioned but you don't have that passport, a FIR copy will be required from the local police station mentioning all the details of how the passport went missing.

If your father's present passport doesn't mention the number of the previous passport (on the last page), you don't need to tell them that he had one.

And for future reference: **Never throw away a passport**. Even an expired or cancelled one.

Answer (score 2):

Although the instructions mention that you should bring all previous passports to the visa interview, they may not necessarily ask to see them. In all US visa interviews I have attended so far, I was never asked to show my old passports.

As far as your father's visa application is concerned, I don't think not having his old passport is a big issue. In case they ask to see the old passport (which is very unlikely) - just state the true facts.

However, as a general guideline, NEVER destroy an expired/cancelled passport. The passport office returns your cancelled passport to you for a reason. You are supposed to keep it with you.